# Alert 30 days before expiry date in C# Windows Forms application using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on a C# Windows Forms project in which I have one form with the following fields

```
Item_ID, Item_Manufacture_Date, Item_Expiry_Date, Price
```

I am saving this into a SQL Server table Item with following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Medicine]
(
    [Item_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Item_Manufacture_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Item_Expiry_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Price] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It is saving properly now and I am displaying all this in datagridview as below respectively.

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = " Select * from Medicine";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

I want to display item 30 days before or some days before its expiry date. By comparing comparing with current date.

For example I want to display those items on 17-01-2018 which will expire on or before 17-02-2018. For that I tried this query, I know this query is wrong please correct me so that I can see those item which will expire in coming 30 days.

```
select 
    Item_Code, ExpiryDate 
from 
    Medicine 
where 
    Date <= GETDATE() - interval 30 day
```

Please help Thank you all.

Comment: Sockpuppet  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48268493/1070452

Comment: Try following :            var results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Item_Expiray_Date") < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)).Select(x => new
            {
                date = x.Field<DateTime>("Item"),
                text = x.Field<string>("Item_Code"),
                man_date = x.Field<DateTime>("Item_Expiry_Date"),
                price = x.Field<string>("Price")
            }).ToList();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **DATEADD**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql

It will look something like

```
SELECT Item_Code, ExpiryDate FROM Medicine WHERE ExpiryDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: This is the answer  I am looking for, it worked for me. Thanks a lot. Thank you very much